# Parse an entire JSON array into a table using 1 key

Tags: json, swift

I need some help with parsing JSON in Swift.

```
[{"Database":"information_schema"}
{"Database":"Tonysnasa"},
{"Database":"camaleonsystems"},
{"Database":"camaleonsystems_back"},
{"Database":"camaleonsystemsfortest"}]
```

^ - Above is my JSON

v - Below is my Swift code.

```
        let jsonDB: String! = jsonResult[0]["Database"] as NSString
        println(jsonDB)

        self.DBList.append(jsonDB)
```

I want to parse all of the "Database:" entries. When I try the method above, I am only able to parse *information_schema*.

How can I parse all the "Database:"'s into my table?

Comment: Consult the documentation for NSArray key-value coding.

Comment: (In Objective-C: `NSArray* databases = [myJsonArray valueForKey:@"Database"];`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like it is an array of dictionaries,to get them all you should be able to use:

```
var jsonDB : [Dictionary<String, String>] = jsonResult
for currentDictionary in jsonDB{
       var currentEntry = currentDictionary["Database"] as String
       println(currentEntry)
       self.DBList.append(currentEntry)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example code!! Would my jsonResult be something like this?

            var jsonResult: Dictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary

Comment: 'Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>' is not convertible to '[Dictionary<String, String>]'

Comment: usually I put nil for the options but that is up to you

Comment: var jsonResult: Dictionary<String, String> = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as Dictionary<String, String>

Comment: you were trying to create jsonResult as a Dictionary, then convert it to a NSDictionary, that makes no sense whatsoever

Comment: 'Dictionary<String, String>' is not convertible to '[Dictionary<String, String>]'

Comment: var jsonResult: [Dictionary<String, String>] = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as [Dictionary<String, String>]